# PHP sentence search

Tags: php, search

Is it possible to search a sentence by inputting first and last words?

Example:
We have a sentence "Hello world this is an example and here is FIRST word, or the start of a sentence that I need to take from here, and here is the LAST word, what means that everything before this word is not needed".

What I want to get:
"FIRST word, or the start of a sentence that I need to take from here, and here is the LAST".

Something like this, and I need it in the PHP.

My idea is to do this with some array, which starts saving words from first word until last word.

Comment: Search where ? in a database? in a string?

Comment: Have you looked into Regular Expressions?  Very useful for doing these kinds of searches in PHP and a lot of other languages.  http://regexone.com/cheatsheet

Comment: Sentence will be taken from the database, as a string

Comment: I am searching for the easiest and lightest way do implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question lacks any effort but is kind of interesting. This is 1 boring old fashioned way

```
<?php

$string="Hello world this is an example and here is FIRST word,
or the start of a sentence that I need to take from here, 
and here is the LAST word, what means that everything 
before this word is not needed";

$first="FIRST";
$last="LAST";

$string=substr($string,strpos($string,$first));                 // Cut Left
$string=substr($string,0,strpos($string,$last)+strlen($last)); //  Cut Right

echo $string;
```

**Output**

```
FIRST word, or the start of a sentence that I need to take from here, 
and here is the LAST
```

But since you didnt put it any effort, dont expect an explanation and or a better way with regexes :)

Comment: Sry for the description, my english is just really bad xD I need just an idea here so I don't expect a good explanation and thx anyway